# Get date from texbox in jQuery dynamic Calender

Tags: c#, jquery, google-calendar-api

I am using dynamicdatetime jQuery (http://code.google.com/p/dyndatetime/) to update datetime in textbox.

[image]

As you see , I am able to get the time from text box but Date is populating in a random way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=txtLoginTime.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
        showsTime: true,
        ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
        daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
        align: "BR",
        electric: false,
        singleClick: false,
        displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
        button: ".next()"

    });
    $("#<%=txtLogOutTime.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
        showsTime: true,
        ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
        daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
        align: "BR",
        electric: false,
        singleClick: false,
        displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
        button: ".next()"

    });
});
</script>
```

Any example would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Format of Date.

```
        ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",
```